# At the time when the book came out, the author had

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence idiomatic:

At the time when the book came out, the author had long since died.

Why does "long since" sound much better with "By the time of the publication of the book" instead?

Is there anyway to keep both "at the time when" and "long since"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The only thing I find odd about the sentence is the use of both *at the time* ***and*** *when*. They aren't both needed. Normally, it would be just one or the other. (And I don't agree that the revised version sounds any better; I think it sounds worse.)

Comment: I’d say “...the author was long since dead.”